# Cannot validate since no PHP executable is set cuando uso una maquina virtual gestionada por Vagrant

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

Esta advertencia aparece en VScode cada vez que lo abro, el detalle esta en que yo no tengo mi ejecutable de PHP en mi maquina local ya que esto desarollando con homestead en una maquina virtual gestionada por Vagrant, la advertencia dice esto: **Cannot validate since no PHP executable is set. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable**

Estoy en ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 1):

Ivandez:

Si no vas a necesitar que se muestren los warnings en el vscode y de momento no vas a tener el ejecutable podrías añadir la siguiente directiva (en caso de no tenerla) en el settings.json de tu vscode:

```
"php.validate.enable": false
```

El fichero se encuentra normalmente en el home de tu usuario, e.g:

```
/home/tuUsuario/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Ya no me aparece una advertencia cada vez que abro vscode pero me gustaria tener la solucion a la pregunta, ya que tener configurado ese path ayuda  a la sintaxis cuando escribes en php.

Comment: Es por lo que comentas en la pregunta, al no tener el ejecutable y no localizarlo el warning va a aparecer cada vez que abras el vscode. De por sí alguna extensión o plugin de php te podría ayudar con el tema de PHP IntelliSense pero muchas requieren de por sí el ejecutable de PHP y algunas con una versión mínima. Es normal que el warning te aparezca al intentar escribir código con algún lenguaje que no tienes instalado.